# Is it possible to automate mobile games with a pc application, if so what language is used and how is it done

Tags: mobile

Alright, so I’ve had some basic experience with java, and some c# on the side, and I was wondering if either could be used to make some type of desktop app that could work on mobile to automate some simple tasks. There’s plenty of programs that can be made and used to automate tasks on pc, and I was wondering if there was something similar for mobile.

Comment: what mobile platform are you wondering about?

Comment: Current iOS build, iOS 13